# testing the python twitter functions with unittest

Tags: python

The below code I have written is for testing my functions but it is failing because I need to include something in the function.What do I need to include?

```
# Importing libraries that are required
import unittest
from http_twitter import get_keyword_tweets
from http_twitter import get_geocode_tweets
from http_twitter import get_keyword_geo_tweets


# Testing the below function whether it is working correct or not.
class Testtwitter(unittest.TestCase):

def test_keyword_tweets(self):
    """
    testing that i am getting correct or not
    """
    res = get_keyword_tweets("CWC15", Count=10)
    self.assertIn("#CWC15", res)

def test_location_tweets(self):
    """
    testing that i am getting location wise tweets or not
    """
    res = get_geocode_tweets("37.774929,-122.419416,1mi", Count=3)
    self.assertIn("#California", res)
 def test_keyword_location_tweets(self):
    """
    testing that i am getting the combination of tweets or not
    """
    res = get_keyword_geo_tweets(keyword="INDvsBAN",
                                 location="19.075984,72.877656,1mi",
                                 Count=3)
    self.assertIn("Rohit", res)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And this is how i am getting when i run the above code"Python filename.py"

```
 FAIL: test_keyword_tweets (__main__.Testtwitter)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "http_twitter_test.py", line 16, in test_keyword_tweets
 self.assertIn("#CWC15", res)
 AssertionError: '#CWC15' not found in [u'578797293337378816RT   @MajidHumayun: Last chance for #Afridi to ................so on
```

please help me on this

Comment: Looks like your tests are working as they are catching problems since  your code is not doing what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

AssertionError indicates your test is failing, that means probably that the string "#CWC15" is not present in res.

Use something like:

```
self.assertIn("#CWC15", res, 'CWC15 not present')
```

instead:

```
self.assertIn("#CWC15", res)
```

and you will have a better message error.

If you have more than a tweet in res, something like: ['tweet1 content','tweet2 content'] and so on, and you want to test if EVERY tweet inside res contains "#CWC15' then you can do something like this

```
for j in res:
   self.assertEqual('#CWC15' in j, True, '#CWC15 not found')
```

If you have only one tweet in your res or you want only test the first tweet:

```
self.assertEqual('#CWC15' in res[0], True, '#CWC15 not found')
```

You can apply this method with `test_location_tweets`

Comment: my problem is not to avoid the error, Is to overcome the problem
and the problem over here is res returns a list from that i need to find out #cwc15 is existed or not.... :)

Comment: thank you ! at keyword point of view it is okay,But in my second defined function i am testing location("37.774929,-122.419416,1mi") wise.So i don't which kind of tweet it is going to be generated. So how can i test that (If by distance how ?)

Comment: Hi, Surendra, can you please give an example of what is returning your function: get_geocode_tweets("37.774929,-122.419416,1mi", Count=3)

Comment: the above cordinates are a location("latitude,longitude,distance")id. so it will return the tweets from that particular area.
Eg output:  
In [2]: get_geocode_tweets('37.774929,-122.419416,1mi',2)  
Out[2]:   
[u'578841052557090816#Healthcare #Job alert: Pharmacist Job near San Francisco, CA | Soliant Health | #SanFranciscoCA, CA http://t.co/wfLU3t00S9',  
 u"578839285501009920S.F. through Italian eyes in Andrea Ponsi\u2019s 'Perceptions\u2019: In 2010, architect Andrea Ponsi published a unique and\u2026 http://t.co/5WrUtnQREH"]